# react state is not updating with localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m working with localstorage. I have some toDos list(its name savedToDos in my code) there and now I m working on button that allows to save changes after editing values of toDos. I save changes in localStorage and then I try to update state to get fresh data from localstorage, but it is not working, changes are not showing correctly. It is working only **when  I reload page - all changes are showing correctly**. Otherwise I've seen in console that localStorage is updating correctly, but when I try to update state with localStorage, state is just doesn't updating, only after reload of page. And without reloading toDo list is showing incorrect updates.

Here is code, main thought in function saveToDo

```
export default function Bar() {

    const LOCAL_TO_DOS = "localToDos"
    const [toDo, setToDo] = React.useState("")
    const [savedToDos, setSavedToDos] = React.useState([])
    const barInput = document.getElementById("barInput")
    const inputRef= React.useRef(null)
    //localStorage.clear()

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        if(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TO_DOS)) {      
            setSavedToDos(
                JSON.parse(
                    localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TO_DOS)
                )
            )
        }
    }, [])

    function handleChange(event){
        setToDo(event.target.value)
    } 
    
    function addNewToDo(){
        if(toDo){
            const localToDo = {
                id: nanoid(), 
                content: toDo
            }
            setSavedToDos([...savedToDos ,localToDo])
            localStorage.setItem(
                LOCAL_TO_DOS, 
                JSON.stringify([...savedToDos,localToDo])
            )
            setToDo("")
            barInput.value = ""
            inputRef.current.focus()
        }
    }
    
    function editToDo(event){
        //if were changes  
        document.getElementById(event.target.parentNode.id)
            .contentEditable="true"
        document.getElementById(event.target.id)
            .style.visibility = "hidden"
        document.getElementById(event.target.id)
            .nextElementSibling.style.visibility = "visible"
    }

    function saveToDo(event){
        document.getElementById(event.target.parentNode.id)
            .contentEditable="false"
        document.getElementById(event.target.id)
            .style.visibility = "hidden" 
        document.getElementById(event.target.id)
            .previousElementSibling.style.visibility = "visible"

        const editedToDo = {
            id: event.target.parentNode.id, 
            content: document.getElementById(
                event.target.parentNode.id
            ).childNodes[0].nodeValue
        }

        let updatedToDos = savedToDos.filter(note => 
            note.id != event.target.parentNode.id
        )
        localStorage.setItem(
            LOCAL_TO_DOS, 
            JSON.stringify([editedToDo,...updatedToDos])
        )

        setSavedToDos(
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_TO_DOS))
        )
    }

    return (
        <div className='bar'>
            <textarea
                ref={inputRef}
                id="barInput"
                //type="text"
                placeholder="new to-do"
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button id="addButton" onClick={addNewToDo}>add</button>
            {savedToDos.length != 0? <>
        {savedToDos.map((savedToDo)=>(
            <div className="toDoArea"  id={savedToDo.id}>
        {savedToDo.content}
        <button  id={nanoid()} className="editButton" onClick={editToDo}>edit</button>
        <button  id={nanoid()} className="saveButton" onClick={saveToDo}>save</button>
        <button  id={nanoid()} className="deleteButton" onClick={deleteTodo}>delete</button>
        </div>
        )) }</> : <p>You have not any tasks</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything was solved and showed correctly after I added key value here

```
 {savedToDos.map((savedToDo)=>(
        <div className="toDoArea" key={savedToDo.id}  id={savedToDo.id}>
    {savedToDo.content}
    <button  id={nanoid()} className="editButton" onClick={editToDo}>edit</button>
    <button  id={nanoid()} className="saveButton" onClick={saveToDo}>save</button>
    <button  id={nanoid()} className="deleteButton" onClick={deleteTodo}>delete</button>
    </div>
    )) }
```